# Silly question: suppose that $f$ has domain $(a,b)$, then does $f$ have a limit as $x$ tends to either $a$ or $b$?

Tags: calculus, limits, soft-question

For example, suppose that $f(x) = x^2$ with domain $(-1,1)$. Then we can take the limit as $x \to -1$ or $x \to 1$?

The function itself is not even defined there. That's my biggest concern.

Comment: What is your definition of a limit?

Comment: You can as well as you can take the limit as $x\to \pm\infty$ when your function is define on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: In Calculus, you might say that there is no limit to indicate that you cannot approach $-1$ and $1$ from either side; with that definition of limit, you could only take the limit as you approach $-1$ from the right, or the limit as you approach $1$ from the left, but not the arbitrary, *two-sided* limit. Later on, with a slightly more general definition of limit that takes into account the domain of the function, you would be able to just talk about “the limit as $x\to 1$”. But in standard, beginning calculus, just $x\to 1^-$ and $x\to -1^+$.

Comment: But the problem is not that $f$ is not defined at $1$ or at $-1$, but rather that $f$ is not defined “everywhere near $1$, except perhaps at $1$”, or “in an open neighborhood of $1$, except perhaps at $1$”, which is often a requirement put on limits at the calculus level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the function to be defined there. Asserting that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$ means (assuming that $a$ is a limit point of the domain $D_f$ of $f$) that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that, if $0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$ and $x\in D_f$, then $\bigl\lvert f(x)-l\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$. As you see, $f$ doesn't need to be defined at $a$.

Comment: Maybe it is worth stressing that *even if* $f$ is defined, the value  of $f(a)$ is completely irrelevant for the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: you can see this from the formal definition given in José's excellent answer. Or more intuitively, consider this "definition":

> We say that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if, as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to *but is not equal to* $a$, $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$.

See, it doesn't really matter that $f(a)$ is not defined in the case where the domain of $f$ is $(a,b)$. All that matters is that we can choose a sequence of $x$s that get arbitrarily close to $a$, even if it does not necessarily ever equal to $a$. Then, we can look at what the value of $f(x)$ tends to, independently of what $f(a)$ is (or even if it is undefined). On the other hand, we can't consider something like $\lim_{x\to(a-1)}f(x)$, because we can't get arbitrarily close to $(a-1)$ while staying in the domain $(a,b)$ of the function (we can at most get to $1$ unit away).

Once you start to learn analysis, you will learn the concept of *limit points* of a set $S$, which are intuitively the set of points which we can get arbitrarily close to without leaving $S$. In this case, we say that $a$ and $b$ are limit points of the set $(a,b)$. In some sense, a point $p$ is a limit point if for a function $f$ defined over $S$, it makes sense to speak of $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=\sin(1/(x-1))$.  Then $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: I don't think this is what was asked.